# Using php to force download a pdf

Tags: php, html, download, http-headers

Im trying to get a website to have a button that forces a download of a pdf.

Heres the html of the button:

```
    <a href=scripts/download.php>
    <input type="image" src="images/download.gif" alt="Submit button"/>
    </a>
```

And the php script so far:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=documents/ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf');
    readfile('documents/ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf');
    ?>
```

This seems to download the file fine but when I go to open it i get this error:

"Adobe Reader could not open 'documents_ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Opened the pdf in a text editor and got this message:

"
**Warning**:  readfile(documents/ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **html/scripts/download.php** on line **4**
"

The document is definitely there though. in html/documents/ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf

Comment: Wrapping an input tag in a link tag is odd

Comment: Most likely something is causing the output to include some invalid pdf content.. maybe the server is throwing an error. Try to open the result file in a text editor

Comment: Ahh i hadnt noticed that, I had done that for another link but didnt notice i still had that

Comment: Have you tried to compare source and downloaded files?

Comment: Make sure there's no trailing spaces after the `?>`, which'd become part of the download. In fact, eliminate the `?>` entirely so this becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried getting rid of the closing PHP tag (the ?>) at the end? It will treat the page as a pure PHP page, removing any possible new lines that might accidentally get appended to the end of the output. This helped me when I was dynamically creating excel files for download, and they were downloading as corrupted. Check out this page for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

From your edited question, it seems like PHP is unable to find the file. Try using an absolute path to the file like so: "c:\blah\de\blah\bloo.pdf" or "c:/blah/de/blah/bloo.pdf". If one of those paths works and downloads correctly, your relative path is incorrect in some way.

Comment: Thats something I didnt know, i thought you always had to close them

But it doesnt solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Try an absolute path in the readfile() call: "c:/html/downloads/ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf" or whatever.

Comment: Hoora! No problem, have a great night :)

Answer (score 29):

```
$file_url = www.example.com/pdffolder/$pdfname;
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$pdfname);
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: > `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$pdfname);`

I would also recommend you encode it just in case ... `urlencode($pdfname)`

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the path to the file and just leave the file name in the content:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=ECM_IT_ResumeDownload.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use Gowon Patterson's download script, it also has hotlink protection:
https://github.com/gowonltd/getter (working link as at 2023)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, a bit late, but to identify the problem properly here:

Your download script is at `scripts/download.php` and the file you want to download is at `documents/[...].pdf`.

Therefore, your `readfile()` function should be traversing to the parent directory (outside of `scripts/`), e.g. `readfile('../documents/[...].pdf');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add : `ob_clean();` just before the first header. This is to avoid blank spaces at the beginning of the file.