# redirect url after updating mysql database error

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am trying to use following code to update mysql database and allow user to download pdf files whose url is in database field. But currently with following code, mysql database get updated **(download_count1 = download_count1 + 1)** but expected url is not opening...instead of that "countupdate1.htm" get downloaded.

current structure of mysql database is :
as follows :

[image]

And I want user to download file with link in download_sublink1 with prefixed url to this download_link1.
e.g. "http://www.mydomain/tickets/download/$['download_sublink1']"

My current code is as follow :

On **downloads.php** page

```
$data=mysql_fetch_array($objTotalRS);

<a href="countupdate1.php?id=<?php echo $data['download_id'];?>" download>Download</a>
```

And on **countupdate1.php** page

```
$download_id = $_GET['id'];
$get_query = "SELECT * FROM es_downloads WHERE download_id = $download_id." ; 
$row = mysql_query($get_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_get_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($row); 

//add 1 to that count 

$count = $row_get_query['download_count1']; 
$new_count = ($count+1); 

//update the table 

$count_query = "UPDATE es_downloads SET download_count1='$new_count' WHERE download_id= $download_id"; 
$result = mysql_query($count_query) or die(mysql_error()); 

//set redirect location and redirect 
$dest = $row_get_query['download_sublink1'];
$destination_url = "http://mydomain/tickets/download/$dest"; 
if ($result)
header("Location: $destination_url"); 
mysql_close($con);
```

With This code count field is getting updated with addition of 1 , But user is not getting respective pdf file...Instead of that he is forced to download **countupdate1.htm** file.

Comment: Have you tried removing download attribute from the <a> tag? you don't want to download countupdate file you want to download the file being returned. if you really need to force a download have a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576861/using-php-to-force-download-a-pdf If this is what your looking for I'll write a more detailed answer

Comment: @DouglasDC3 I just tried with suggestion..."Cannot modify header information - headers already sent " error is shown

Comment: Where did you try to set the headers. Headers have to be set before you start returning data or load html.

Comment: @DouglasDC3 ohh got why error is there.... in countupdate1.php, at top, database connection code is there and i have added echo"success" if connected... just removed that line and now all code is working along with download in <a> tag also.